# What is 汉白玉 and is it 大理石?

Tags: translation, meaning

[汉白玉](https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B1%89%E7%99%BD%E7%8E%89) is translated to English as "White Marble".

Is that translation correct? Is it a form of [大理石](https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E7%90%86%E7%9F%B3)?

And if it is a form of marble then is it a valuable, expensive form or a cheap form?

And is there an English translation of this form of white marble (just as there is Himalayan Marble and Carrara Marble and Calcutta Marble and etc.)?

Comment: There's a dictionary called 辞海, which might explain such words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the links on your post:

> 但制作雕像的**白色大理岩**也称为**大理岩**
>
> (But the **white marble** that's for making statue is also called **marble**)

'white marble' is one kind of 'marble'

> '汉白玉'就是**纯白色的大理石**
>
> 'Han white jade' is **pure white marble**

汉白玉 is not actual jade, but a marble that is pure white

> *Is that translation correct? Is it a form of 大理石?*
>
> *is there an English translation of this form of white marble?*

Search 'white marble' image and you can find many pictures that we would call 白色的大理石, but most of them are not pure white.

汉白玉 should be translated as '**pure white marble**' and it is still a kind of 大理石 (marble)

*There is one [pure white marble](https://ariastonegallery.com/inspiration/hanoi-pure-white-bathroom/) image I found online. It came from [Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanoi)*

*Hanoi is in North Vietnam, neighboring China*

[云石](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BA%91%E7%9F%B3)(cloud stone = marble) is another name for 大理石

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know if this specific type of pure white marble has a name in English? And how valuable it is compared with other white marbles?

Comment: @Johan88  Unlike other so call white marble, 汉白玉 is pure white, without other color mixed in. It is a very unique feature. I think you can just call it "Pure white marble." You see the link ' Hanoi pure white marble' . is named so base on where it came from. If it is  from Yunnan, it would be called 云南汉白玉 (Yunnan pure white marble). As for the value of this type of stone, just search online, and compare the pure white marble price with color marble's price . You can see the difference